# jQuery Mobile 1.0.1 Google Maps doesn't show the map first time after Reload Refresh works

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

My problem is everytime i open the website; first time the map doesn't show up, after a reload/refersh it works and shows the map.

Here is my google maps code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  var infowindow;

  function initialize(position) {
    //var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(48.195201,16.369547);
    var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 15
    });
    var a = new google.maps.Marker({position: pyrmont,map: map,icon:'catal.png'});
    var request = {
      location: pyrmont,
      radius: 500,
      types: ['restaurant']
    };
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.search(request, callback);
  }

  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.ZERO_RESULTS){
   alert('zero results near this location');
    }
  }

  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(    place.name
                                +'<br/>'+place.vicinity);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
  });
</script>
```

And here how i use it with jquery:

```
<div data-role="page" id="restaurant">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="index.html" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
        <h1>Restaurants</h1>    
    </div> 

    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="map" style="width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are waiting for the `window.load` event to fire which will only fire on full-page-refreshes. Here is the offending code:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
});
```

You can use jQuery to bind to the `pageinit` event for your `#restautant` page:

```
$(document).delegate('#restaurant', 'pageinit', function () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
});
```

This will trigger the `initialize()` function when the `#restaurant` pseudo-page is initialized (which will happen once each time it's added to the DOM).

Here is the documentation for the `pageinit` event (as well as all the other jQuery Mobile events): http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: hmm sorry i am a newbie, so where should i add these lines?

Comment: The first code snippet is from your code, and it should be replaced by something similar to the second snippet (the exact code *should* work). The difference between the two is that the second uses event delegation and it binds to an event more suitable for the application.